# definition query and mosaic dataset from gdb ArcMap 10.1 SP1

Tags: arcgis-10.1, layers, arcpy, definition-query, python-addin

I have a Python AddIn Combobox to select a value from the drop-down list. This value changes the definition query of the layers in mxd. This works fine for "normal" feature classes, not for a mosaic dataset. On the Layer Properties dialog box the DefintionQuery tab is empty.

```
layer_lst = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT"))

for layer in layer_lst:

   if layer.name in ('dted_hillshade','dted_dem6x6') and layer.supports("DEFINITIONQUERY"):

      layer.definitionQuery = "\"NAME\"=\'000E00N.DT2\'"
      arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

Does anyone one know a workaround to set a correct Definition query for mosaic dataset?

Comment: Anyone find a programmatic solution?

Answer (score 1):

I overlooked the symptom you described so had thought you might be encountering [**NIM067173**](http://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/TklNMDY3MTcz) which should have been fixed by 10.1 or **[NIM076742](http://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/TklNMDc2NzQy)** which seems to still be an open issue.  However, it sounds like you may be coming up against something different.